# Controlling two chrome instances through Cucumber scenario, driven by Watir Webdriver

Tags: cucumber, watir

I am working on a web application, where I receive a phone call, which is initiated by another web application. To achieve this, I need to open two chrome browsers having two different URLs. I am using cucumber to write scenario and watir webdriver to drive the script. I have implemented Page Object Model as a part of framework. I tried making some changes to support files - i.e., hook.rb, env.rb and driver.rb. But it's not working out. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: You should be able to just initialize 2 browser instances - eg `browser1 = Watir::Browser.new` and `browser2 = Watir::Browser.new`. If that isn't working, you'll need to share more of what you tried and exactly what is not working out.

Comment: Here is the code base - https://github.com/fagunbhavsar/rtcamp-assignment - What I am trying to do here is - to open two browser instances - so I tried putting some hacks at https://github.com/fagunbhavsar/rtcamp-assignment/tree/master/features/support but it didn't work so asked the question here

Comment: Sorry, it's not obvious to me where you're trying to do work with the 2 browsers (ie where it is failing). I did noticed that the `Driver` class is using a class variable, `@@client`, to store the browser instance. If you're using this `Driver` class to open both browsers, using the class variable is likely the issue.